# How to drag and drop Object3D elements with three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I took [this](http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_interactive_draggablecubes.html) example for drag&drop objects, it works perfect. But now I want to group some elements to drag&drop them together. I replaced the Cubes from the example with some Spheres and grouped them together in an Object3D().

```
var data = [[0,10],[50,20],[100,7],[150,18],[200,15],[250,3],[300,10],[350,25]];
var group = new THREE.Object3D();
    for(var i = 0; i< data.length; i++){            
        var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.SphereGeometry(data[i][1],20,20), sphereMaterial);
        mesh.position.y = data[i][0];
        mesh.updateMatrix();
        group.add(mesh);            
    }
objects.push(group);
scene.add(group);
```

But I can't select this group of objects in my scene :( What I'm doing wrong? Isn't it possible to select a group? Or how must it look like?

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to tell without the code, but i think you might be using .intersectObjects(objects), you should try using .intersectObjects(objects, true) instead.

Here is the documentation :

.intersectObjects( objects, recursive )

objects — The objects to check for intersection with the ray.

recursive — If set, it also checks all descendants of the objects. Otherwise it only checks intersecton with the objects.
checks all intersection between the ray and the objects with or without the descendants.

[three.js Raycaster](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Core/Raycaster)

Comment: When I do  .intersectObjects(objects, true), you can drag the single spehres. But I don't want that! I want to move the whole group of spheres at once.

Comment: You need to take the parent of the selected interested object and drag that.

Comment: That was a simple but usefull hint!
I added a "parent" to "INTERSECTED = intersects[ 0 ].object.parent;" also to the SELECTED and it works! :D
But now every geometry has to be in a group for beeing dragged. That's not nice but I can live with that for now.